# How do I add a column to data frame with a letter representing a date range in another column

Tags: r

I have a large environmental dataset where I want to add a column and then assign a letter to the rows in the new column A, B, C, ... L based on a date range in another column. My code so far is

```
prec <- read.csv("precipitation.csv") #read file
prec_DI <- subset(prec, Location=="Dauphin Island") #subset one location
```

This creates an output like such:

[image]

```
prec_DI$Date <- as.Date(strptime(prec_DI$Date, format="%Y%m%d")) #convert date column to R format
df.DI<-data.frame(sumPrec=tapply(prec_DI$Prec, factor(prec_DI$Date), sum)) #sum all values for each date
df.DI$Date<-row.names(df.DI) #add a row names column
DI10 <- subset(df.DI, Date>="2010-05-17"& Date<="2010-10-31") #subset data based on a date range
```

Now the output looks like this:
[image]

I don't care about the row names being the same as the Date column, I can easily change that.
I tried to add a new empty column by using

```
DI10$Period <- DI10
```

but this created:
[image]

Instead, I want to create a new column where date range 2010-05-17 - 2010-06-03 is assigned "A", range 2010-03-04 - 2010-03-16 is assigned "B", and so on. I would greatly appreciate any help on this, I'm sure it's a straightforward question but I am just starting to learn.

As requested I am adding this output

```
structure(list(sumPrec = structure(c(0.4, 1.6, 1.9, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7), .Dim = 6L,
.Dimnames = list(c("2010-05-18", "2010-05-26", "2010-05-29", "2010-05-30",
"2010-05-31", "2010-06-01"))), Date = c("2010-05-18", "2010-05-26", 
"2010-05-29", "2010-05-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-01" )), 
.Names = c("sumPrec", "Date"), row.names = c("2010-05-18", "2010-05-26", 
"2010-05-29", "2010-05-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-01" ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you include your data, e.g. copy-and-paste the output from `dput(head(DI10))` in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added it to the question.

Comment: Where is it? I don't see a `dput()`

Comment: No, please don't paste a screenshot; paste the actual text output so that other users can copy and paste the text.

Comment: Update: I tried to just add two letters (A and B) by using `DI10$Period <- if(DI10$Date>="2010-05-17" & DI10$Date<="2010-05-28"){
  "A"
} else {
  "B"
}` But I got the error message _In if (DI10$Date >= "2010-05-17" & DI10$Date <= "2010-05-28") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used_ and it created a column with all "A"s.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here's the text: structure(list(sumPrec = structure(c(0.4, 1.6, 1.9, 1.3, 1.4, 
1.7), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = list(c("2010-05-18", "2010-05-26", 
"2010-05-29", "2010-05-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-01"))), Date = c("2010-05-18", 
"2010-05-26", "2010-05-29", "2010-05-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-01"
)), .Names = c("sumPrec", "Date"), row.names = c("2010-05-18", 
"2010-05-26", "2010-05-29", "2010-05-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-01"
), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.  First, convert your date column to a POSIXct class object, representing a calendar date:

```
DI10$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(DI10$Date))
```

Then, you can either use the `cut.POSIXt()` function

```
DI10$Period <- cut.POSIXt(
  DI10$Date, 
  breaks = as.POSIXct(as.Date(c("1970-01-01", "2010-05-17", "2010-05-29", "9999-12-31"))),
  labels = c("C", "A", "B"))
```

which cuts your date range using the breaks provided (where the first and last date represent the outer bounds); or you can make a dataframe with start/end dates and labels, e.g.

```
dates <- data.frame(Start = c("2010-05-17", "2010-03-04"),
                    End =   c("2010-05-28", "2010-03-16"),
                    Label = c("A", "C"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dates$Start <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(dates$Start))
dates$End <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(dates$End))
```

and then use `sapply` to iterate through your dates to do the `Period` assignment

```
DI10$Period <- sapply(DI10$Date, function(x) {
  out <- dates$Label[x >= dates$Start & x <= dates$End]
  if (length(out) == 0) "B" else out
})
```

Output:

```
DI10
#            sumPrec                Date Period
# 2010-05-18     0.4 2010-05-18 08:00:00      A
# 2010-05-26     1.6 2010-05-26 08:00:00      A
# 2010-05-29     1.9 2010-05-29 08:00:00      B
# 2010-05-30     1.3 2010-05-30 08:00:00      B
# 2010-05-31     1.4 2010-05-31 08:00:00      B
# 2010-06-01     1.7 2010-06-01 08:00:00      B
```

Comment: The first option works beautifully! Thank you so much!